# How do I fix this error in Google's prebuilt Deep Learning image?

Tags: google-dl-platform

I'm running Google's prebuilt Deeping Learning Image with Tensorflow/CUDA 10.0. I'm getting this error message:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you select: "Install NVIDIA GPU driver automatically on first startup?"

Answer (score 1):

`libcuda.so.1` is a file that is a part of Nvidia driver. If, for some reasons, driver is not installed, you can run the following command that will install it:

```
sudo /opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh
```

Comment: Is there an updated version of this answer?